# How can I roll back Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

I face a very frequent problem: I am new to Ubuntu and I like experimenting with different softwares and environments, but either after installing them or after uninstalling them I can not log in into my machine after reboot. Something goes wrong at boot and I left with access to terminal only. Can someone suggest me what should I do? Can I restore my Ubuntu a previous point (I have not created a restore point before installing any package because I don't know how to do it)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to either:

- read how to install Ubuntu on BTRFS. Btrfs is a filesystem that can roll back in time.
- In your Ubuntu, install Virtualbox, then install Ubuntu into VirtualBox and do your experiments there. It is safe and also provides the rollback capability. Trnsfer only changes you are sure of into your working Ubuntu.

The second one is easier.